# What's the name of a permutation where repetition is possible?

Tags: combinatorics

I need to know the name of something that looks like a permutation but really isn't. Given a set $S$ of $n$ elements, I need to know what's the name of the mathematical procedure which I use to generate **ordered** subsets of $m$ elements each, where $1 \leq m \leq n$. Elements in $S$ are unique, like in normal sets, but in each of the generated subsets, they don't need to be. The best analogy for this is that $S$ is the alphabet and the ordered subsets are all words with $m$ letters, only all combinations of $m$ letters count as valid words (if $m$ is $4$, then *wzzw* would be a valid word).

What's is this called? I need to know so I can look for an algorithm that can perform this and learn it. All the famous ones are about performing real permutations (meaning no repetitions). So I know the name is definitely *not* permutation.

EDIT since @jonaslj asked me to let him know how would I implement this algorithm as a cartesian power, here it is.

First of all, in my solution, I would need to wrap the objects that make up the elements of the set S and the temporary n-tuples in a concatenable version of themselves, in a way that I would have defined the + operation as a concatenation between elements such that if element 1 (e1) is the letter **a**, for instance, and element 2 (e2) is the letter **b**, then e1 + e2 = **ab** (note that this is not *a times b*. It's a *new letter*, for the purposes of the ongoing algorithm. Generally speaking, what I'm saying is that, for my algorithm to work, I need first to give a tuple the ability for it to be concatenated with any element in $S$ to generate a longer tuple).

With that out of the way, the basic algorithm is this:

```
    cartesianProduct ( multiset1 As List Of Any, multiset2 As List Of Any)
    Returns List of Any    
    {
        //the result
        Declare result As List Of Any;

        Declare counter, i, j As Integer;
        counter = 0;

        for ( i = 0; i < multiset1.size; i++ )
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < multiset2.size; j++ )
            {
                //bellow is the concatenation thing I spoke so longly about
                result[counter] = multiset1[i] + multiset2[j];
                counter++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

To use this as a cartesian power (to use my own example, all words of 4 letters using the alphabet and allowing gibberish and repetition), all I would need to do would be to call this once, then again, over the result and the original set, then once more, this time over the result of the second call and the original set. And if I want 1 more letter, I use the new result and call it one more time, with the latest result, passing also the original set (the alphabet, in the case of this example).

There are extreme cases (like empty sets for example) which I didn't bother to include the code for in here. I'm not even sure if this works for real. I don't have access to a real desktop at the moment, and testing this for reals right now would be kind of annoying, but I believe it would work, as simple tests have shown.

Comment: That's a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Comment: What you are describing is a [permutation with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition).

Comment: It seems to be both, and more specifically in the case of a cartesian product, it seems to be a cartesian power. I'll check if there's an algorithm to implement a cartesian power.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your case boils down to finding all $m$-tuples of integers $(a_1,...,a_m)$ such that $1 \leq a_i \leq a_{i+1} \leq n$ for all $i$. Because if we assume that $S = \{s_1,\ldots,s_n\}$ where the $s_i$'s are ordered, then this $m$-tuple corresponds to the [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) $\{s_{a_1}, \ldots, s_{a_m}\}$. So an algorithm for finding tuples would be something like:

- Choose a value $a_1 \in \{1,...,n\}$,
- for i = 2...m-1 choose a value $a_i$ s.t. $a_{i-1} \leq a_i \leq n$.

Now, if all elements in the tuple are different, they correspond 1-1 with a set of size $m$. If two elements are equal, they correspond to a set with size $m-1$, but there are $m-1$ different elements that could be the one that occur twice, eg. $\binom{m-1}{m-2}$ different possible tuples for each set of size $m-1$. If there are $m-2$ different elements in the tuple, this corresponds to a set with size $m-2$, but there are $\binom{m-1}{m-3}$ different ways these elements could be chosen to give such a tuple for each set of size $m-2$. In general you get

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{m-2}  \binom{m}{m-i} \binom{m-1}{m-1-i} $$

different such ordered tuples.

Comment: In a multiset, elements need not be unique.   The OP specifically says that the elements in the set $S$ are unique.  Also, in a [permutation of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets), each element is used just once.  The OP wishes to use elements in $S$ repeatedly.   This is a [permutation with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition).

Comment: The set $S$ is not a multiset, but the subsets he is looking for are. And I think both calling them "permutations with repetition" or "tuples" are fine.

Comment: I think you are both right. This is, if I understand permutations with repetitions correctly, because the section is really small. But I didn't understand the algorithm very much. Did you abstract the elements from S leaving only their indexes, so now S is a set of integers from 1 to n? If that's what you did, why those integers need to appear in crescent order in each n-tuple (or multiset)? If this algorithm has a name, can you tell me, and maybe there's a video explanation for it that I can look for?

Comment: Yes, now I consider $S$ as a set of integers from 1 to n based on the ordering of the elements of $S$ you implicitly assume exist. So without stating it directly, I assumed that $\{s_1,...,s_n\}$ are ordered. This ensures that an ordered tuple of indices corresponds to an ordered subset of $S$. Unfortunately, I don't know if the algorithm has a name.

Comment: It may be less efficient, but I think I'll be pursuing the cartesian power road. It's more intuitive for someone who's not really into hard abstractions, like myself. If I visualise it in terms of a cartesian product over a cartesian product, etc, n times, recursively, it gets kind of simple. Even if it's not the best solution, it will be my solution. Then after it, I will learn a better one, but first I need one I fully understand, so I can actually grasp the problem itself. After that, I'll come back and take a look at your closed solution.

Comment: That could probably work too, although it's not obvious to me how, so please write your solution here when you find one.

Answer (score 1):

There are

- [$n$-tuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) $(a_1,...,a_n)$, generealizations of pairs, triples, quadruples, etc. They are ordered and allow repetition. They are essentially functions $f:\{1,...,n\}\to S$.
- [sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) $(a_i)=a_1,a_2,a_3,... $, which are like tuples but have infinitely many elements. They are functions $f:\Bbb N\to S$.

In theoretical computer science "words" are in some sense $n$-tuples over an alphabet. The set of all words (ordered tuples) is denoted $S^*$ and is called [Kleene hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) (or Kleene star, etc.).